# Pros and cons of each Java EE server for developing within Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Eclipse Java EE has a lot of server adapters allowing development against many different application servers like JBoss, Glassfish and WebSphere.

Frequently you can benefit from using another server for developing new features than for production, simply because it may be able to deploy changes much faster and when the functionality is in place, you can iron out bugs for the production platform.

Unfortunately *finding* that server is a time consuming process, where the experiences of others are invaluable.

If you have experience with any server with an Eclipse Server Adapter, please add your findings and your recommendation.  I believe that the following is of interest:

- Does saving a file trigger an update in the server, giving save edit+reload browser functionality?
- How fast is a deployment? (Saved a JSP? Java class? Static file?)
- Can the actual server be downloaded by the Server Adapter Wizard allowing for easy installation?
- Are there known bugs and issues with suitable work-arounds?
- Is debugging fully supported?  Is profiling?
- Would you recommend this server?

---

Note:  Eclipse can also work with Tomcat but that is a *web container*, which cannot deploy EAR files.

Comment: I like this question.  It is well written, asks for specific criteria, and isn't begging for a flame war.

Comment: If you are using WAS full profile in production, check out the Liberty profile for development - http://wasdev.net/

Answer (score 1):

**Glassfish v3 Java EE 6**

- Saving a file updates the server.
- Deployment for smaller EAR files are sub-second.  For XHTML files (facelets) this is fast enough for save+reload.
- Server must be downloaded manually, and the latest patches downloaded from within the admin console running on port 4848.
- Debugging is fully supported.  Do not know about profiling.

Bugs:  It appears that Java EE Utility Projects are not properly deployed as their classes are not available to the rest of the EAR.

Recommended: Yes.